# Search for partial decimal, then grab data in the cell next to it, then submit a count

Tags: excel

I am wrapping up a project of mine and I'm having difficulty finishing one of the last formulas.

I've embedded a picture, I am trying to do a count based off two columns.

The first column is the workpoint.  In this column I need to identify any workpoint that has a .5 in it.

The second workpoint is the material matching that work point.

Essentially I need to scan column Z for anything with .5  -- Then I need it to compare the data in column AA on whether or not it is Wood or concrete.

At this point it would spit out just a number count of how many .5's are wood, and how many .5's are concrete. (The comparison doesn't need to be made in one formula, can just do a count on wood, then I'll change the other to concrete).

I've tried using COUNTIF, but found that it doesn't like partial matches with decimals.  I've had luck coming up with a count for all of the .5's in the column - however I haven't been able to wrap my brain around how to compare it to the materials and then spit out a count.  The array formula I've used to successfully count the .5's is below.

Any help is greatly appreciated

=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(".5",Z:Z)),0,1))

[Snippit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgZC8.jpg)

Comment: None of the numbers in your example resolve true to `=MOD(A1, 1)=0.5`.

Comment: `CountIfs` with `"*.5*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND(".5",Z:Z))*(AA:AA="wood"))
```

although it would count 1.537 etc. as well as 1.5. It would also be slow applying it to a whole column, but that might not matter if you are only using it a couple of times.

You could narrow the search to numbers ending in exactly .5 like this:-

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND(".5|",Z:Z&"|"))*(AA:AA="wood"))
```

Another way as suggested by @Jeeped is to use MOD:-

```
=SUM((MOD(Z2:Z999,1)=0.5)*(AA2:AA999="wood"))
```

but using Z:Z it would fail if there was a header row, so I have used a fixed range.

All of these are array formulae and need to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much, it does indeed work.  You've been great, thanks!